# Parsing input text in a strange format

Tags: python, string, parsing, line

I have an input document with data in the following format. The three example target words are 'overlook', 'lettered', and 'resignation'. Each is followed by a list of synonyms or, if none were found, just the word None. Because the target word is not included in the list of synonyms, I've prepended "tgws_" to it for identification purposes. Input document:

```
tgws_overlook
['omit', 'forget', 'ignore', 'discount']

tgws_overlook

['verb']
tgws_lettered

None
tgws_lettered

['adj.']
tgws_resignation

[ 'dejection', 'surrender', 'pessimism', 'defeatism', 'acceptance', 'abdication']
tgws_resignation

['noun']
```

Note that each target word appears twice; I only want it to appear once in the output. I need to read each line in, and then output a new document with the data looking as follows. Here, though, I'm just printing the output. If the string beginning with tgws_ is a new string, ie if it hasn’t been seen before, then save it in a variable called target_word. If it has been seen before, then ignore it.  In the case of None, we just print the target word followed by a hyphen and the part of speech (pos), followed by a dash and the word None, all on one line.  Otherwise, we print out the target word on one line, pos on the next line, and synonyms on a third line. Here's what I'm looking for:

```
tgws_overlook
POS: verb
['omit', 'forget', 'ignore', 'discount']

tgws_lettered – adj. - None

tgws_resignation
POS: noun
[ 'dejection', 'surrender', 'pessimism', 'defeatism', 'acceptance', 'abdication']
```

Here's the code I wrote, that isn't quite doing it. It repeats targetwords like 6 times... Something is wrong with the loop. And perhaps there is a better way to do this...

```
def main():
    wordlist = []
    current_word = ""
    target_word = ""

    with open(input_filename, "r") as infile:
        counter = 0
        pos = ""

        for line in infile:
          
          if line.startswith("tgws_"):
            target_word = line
          if line.startswith(("['adv.']", "['pronoun']", "['conjunction']", "['noun']", "['verb']", "['adj.']" )):
              pos = line.strip("['']")
          elif line.startswith("['"):
              wordlist = line
          elif line.startswith("None"):
            wordlist = "[None]"
          print(target_word, pos, wordlist)
          current_word = target_word

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You should only do the `print()` after you've set `wordlist` or `pos`, not every time through the loop.

Comment: Removed all but one. Still prints out each target word six times...

Comment: I recommend using a dictionary to parse the input into and then writing that dictionary back out to a new file.

Comment: You can also simplify this by treating lines like `['adv.']` and `['adv.', 'pronoun']` the same. They are both lists. You can strip off the `[` and `]` characters then split the remaining string on `,`. If there is no `,` then `split()` will return a list with one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do the printing in the loop that reads the file. Create a dictionary that maps the target word to the wordlist and part of speech. At the end, print the dictionary in the format you want.

```
import ast, collections

def main():
    words = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    target_word = None
    parts_of_speech = {"adv.", "pronoun", "conjunction", "noun", "verb", "adj."}

    with open(input_filename, "r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith("tgws_"):
                target_word = line
            elif line.startswith("["):
                data = ast.literal_eval(line)
                if len(data) == 1 and data[0] in parts_of_speech:
                    words[target_word]['pos'] = data[0]
                else:
                    words[target_word]['wordlist'] = data
            elif line.strip() == 'None':
                words[target_word]['wordlist'] = None

    for word, features in words.items():
        if features.get('wordlist']) is None:
            print(f'{word} - {features["pos"]} - None')
        else:
            print(word)
            print(f'POS: {features['pos']}')
            print(features['wordlist'])
        print()
```

You can also use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse the lists, rather than ad hoc string processing.

Comment: thanks -- It's much closer. The first two words print out correctly:
tgws_overlook

POS: verb
['omit', 'forget', 'ignore', 'discount']

tgws_lettered
 - adj. - None

But then I'm getting a KeyError: 'wordlist' on this line:
---> 46         if features['wordlist'] is None:

I'm running this in a jupyter notebook, btw

Comment: Are any of the words missing a wordlist or `None` in the file?

Comment: No, the sample input is exactly as I posted above. That's what I'm testing on. The actual document will have more target words but the format is the same.

Comment: The wordlist doesn't begin with `['`, it has a space between `[` and `'`. Why isn't it formatted consistently?

Comment: I've changed the code to just look for an initial `[` instead of `['`

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake when I wrote out the short input file. Thanks for your help -- I'm marking this as solved, and will study what you've done.